# UML Activity diagram how to show game ends when time has passed?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

[image]

When 20 seconds passes, the player unlocks poison.  Poison can be dropped to slow down the enemy, or the player can accidentally eat his own poison and slow down.

I want to show that the player wins after 60 seconds has passed.  I thought I would show it as a loop looping the 20seconds 3 times but that would be incorrect because the player can only unlock the poison once.

Would the best way of showing this be to draw a rectangle around the entire diagram and just state (after 60 seconds, player wins)? - and have it lead to an end circle?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than polling for the timer you can show timers and an interrupt using a Interruptible Regions like this:

[image]

The 20 seconds timer to the left will hit after 20 seconds when the region has been entered. It will continue with any arbitrary action (here `Unlock potion`).

All actions within the region (the dashed box) can experience also an exception that will transfer the flow to the `Timeout` after 60 seconds. If needed you could mix actions that will not be hit by the timer outside the region.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know timers could be used like this.  I will be applying this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the point where you get start time and add point when you check if current time - start time == 60sec.

Comment: That has done the trick.  I was getting confused between state diagrams and activity diagrams.